Running ffmpeg in Docker environment on AWS EC2
I want to use FFMPEG inside my Java application.
I want to instal ffmpeg in environment where this app is running.
My current Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Stage 2: Run the application
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/application.jar ./app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=pr", "app.jar"]

I simply built a docker image by running docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t repo/app:1.0 .
Then in AWS Console I run docker run and pull built image.
Everyone writes about adding
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg

but I cannot do it as I'm building image on MacOS and I do no have apt-get command.
When I was trying to pull some image form DockerHub FFMPEG could not be found.
I tried this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg
and declared DockerFile as:
# Stage 1: Build the application
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Stage 2: Install ffmpeg
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:latest AS ffmpeg

# Stage 3: Run the application
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/application.jar ./app.jar
COPY --from=ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=pr", "app.jar"]

but still it did not work. I get:
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm using Amazon Linux on EC2.
Can someone get me on the right track?

The Docker image is built in an isolated Linux environment, so you'd RUN apt-get ... in your Dockerfile (and more specifically in the final stage).  It doesn't matter here that you have a MacOS host, the container can't see or use pacakages that are installed only on the host.

@DavidMaze I was in the linked question, but seems like I do not understand it clearly. When I add apt-get... to my Dockerfile I get:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127 while building

It looks like the openjdk image by default is built on Oracle Linux, but it's also unsupported.  Something like eclipse-temurin:17 will be based on Ubuntu and will have APT available.

@DavidMaze  It works now. Eclipse-temuring:17 works. Gosh... I spent on it couple of hours. Thanks a lot!
